# Events relationship not working

Tags: yii2

I have model named Events with the following structure.

```
class Events extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    const EVENT_SEND_EMAIL_TO_CREATER = 'send-email-to-creater-of-event';

    public function init()
    {
        $this->on(self::EVENT_SEND_EMAIL_TO_CREATER, [$this, 'sendEmailToCreaterOfEvent']);
    }
    .....


    public function getParents()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Parents::className(), ['ID' => 'CreatedByUserID'])->select([ 'ID', 'Name' ]);
    }

    public function sendEmailToCreaterOfEvent($event)
    {
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($event->parents); exit;
    }
}
```

The above event is triggered whenever a parent creates a new **Event**. But it giving the following error:

> Getting unknown property: yii\base\Event::parents

Is relationship don't work within events? Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$event` refers to the instance of [`\yii\base\Event`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-event.html) that was triggered, not to your active record `Events`. To access the object that triggered an event, you can use [`Event::sender`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-event.html#$sender-detail):

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($event->sender->parents); exit;
```

Alternatively since the event handler is in the same class as the object, you can use `$this`:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->parents); exit;
```